# Why do the blue angels sometimes dump fuel during maneuvers?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance

Watching the blue angels I noticed that their was fuel being dumped from the fuel dump nozzle, on top of the vertical stabilizer. Why is this?

Comment: That's not actually what you saw. Condensation from pulling G's or otherwise loading the vertical stab - not fuel dumping, which would be pointless, not to mention environmentally unfriendly.

Comment: @RalphJ No this wasn't condensation from pulling gs. This was fuel coming from the fuel dump nozzles. The plane was in formation and was the only one doing it. It also was not a smoke trail.

Comment: @Boeing787 Do you have photo/video evidence of this? It's highly unlikely: I can only imagine serious pilot error or mechanical failure as explanations. Much more likely is that you misinterpreted what you saw. It can be hard to make out this kind of detail on a jet from a distance traveling hundreds of knots (mph).

Comment: https://youtu.be/iMX8NyCdG90
Look at the plane to the left

Comment: Either it's smoke trail or the [frecce tricolori](https://youtu.be/IlYgCXC40c0) use green, white and red kerosene:)

Comment: The video from the comment yesterday shows the standard smoke generator. "Why only 1 jet was using it then" might be a worthwhile question, but that's the standard smoke.

Comment: What about this

https://www.flickr.com/photos/avgeekjoe/20342396120

Answer (score 3):

What you’re seeing there is not fuel dumping, it’s smoke generated from dumping linseed oil into the exhaust of the starboard engine. A Blue Angels F/A-18E/F are specially modified from a stock Rhino, to include, but not limited to, the removal of the 20 mm cannon, and replacement with an oil tank which can feed into the exhaust on command from the pilot.  This produces that characteristic, thick, white, billowy smoke trail for airshows.

Comment: Smoke can also [be coloured](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IlYgCXC40c0&feature=youtu.be) :)

Comment: The Blues have done so in the past, but the last time they did was in the early 1970s when the team flew modified F-4J Phantoms with smoke generators installed in dummy Sparrow missile casings on the belly of the A/C.  This was not carried on when the team flew the A-4F and F/A-18A/B/C/D/E/F aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

The [video](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95390/why-do-the-blue-angels-sometimes-dump-fuel-during-maneuvers#comment262937_95390) you have linked is way too blurry to give a correct answer ([here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iMX8NyCdG90&feature=youtu.be) a link's copy)

On the contrary, the [picture](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95390/why-do-the-blue-angels-sometimes-dump-fuel-during-maneuvers#comment263047_95390) you have linked does actually show fuel being dumped ([here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/avgeekjoe/20342396120) a link's copy)

Note that video and picture refer to two different episodes, we don't know to which one you are referring to.

On the F-18, fuel dump outlets are on the vertical stabiliser as visible in this cutaway [(source)](https://www.pinterest.es/pin/333759022366324312/):

[image: F-18 cutaway]

Fuel is normally jettisoned in case of emergency in order to reduce weight at landing. The picture you've posted might eventually refer to a test.

Comment: https://youtu.be/MF_UJ3tQILY look at 43:45 minutes. Fuel is clearly dumped front the top of the vertical stabilizer.

Comment: @Boeing787: Interesting to note that it happens just after a cobra manoeuvre. It might be that due to this manoeuvre a bit of fuel escaped towards the outlet and got ejected as soon as the airplane levelled